# Azure Service Fabric and Scheduled Tasks

Tags: scheduled-tasks, azure-service-fabric, azure-scheduler

Say you have 30+ console applications running on the Windows machine which can invoked manually or through Windows Scheduled Tasks, **what would be recommended way to move to/implement them in Service Fabric?**

One way of implementing this would be as one Service Fabric application with many stateless services (`Reliable Actor` using Timers/Reminders) each listening to the Service Bus queue/topic, and then use Azure Scheduler to send messages to the queue/topic.

What would be the pros/cons of such implementation? [This article seems to list few of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002809/azure-service-fabric-and-message-queues).

What would be other ways to implement this?

Seems like some people are trying to advocate for including [pub/sub framework](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/293901-service-fabric/suggestions/7752963-reliable-pub-sub-framework) into Service Fabric, if that becomes part of Service Fabric would that a valid option?

Answer (score 3):

I would look at using Azure Functions, this would be great for simplicity and trendy being Serverless compute, meaning no need to spin up and configure a bus or queue, then use Stateless reliable API services and have the Azure timed Function call the stateless service directly.

See here for a start:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/

This Video is doing a timer with db clean up by no reason why this couldn't be a HTTP call.

[Video](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/create-an-event-processing-azure-function/)

Comment: That looks like an interesting option. I'll consider it.

Answer (score 3):

I like your idea of converting the console applications to actors and using reminders. However, I don't see the need for Service Bus or the Azure Scheduler.

It seems to me that you only need to expose a few API methods on the actors. One to create/modify the run schedule, and a second that would allow the actor to be manually/immediately invoked (while still maintaining turn-based concurrency). The actor could store its full schedule internally, but it only only ever needs to calculate the *next* time to execute - and set the reminder accordingly.

Also, keep in mind that actor reminders are triggered under all circumstances, whereas a timer stopped if Service Fabric deactivates the actor.

Comment: That's good idea, but it would still require another way to call APIs, which in my opinion is use case for Azure Scheduler.